# Javascript, check a field for any value, and skip if occupied

Tags: javascript

Okay folks,

I apologize if this has been asked before, I searched all of yesterday for a solution and came up empty handed. Perhaps I am searching the incorrect terms... but I digress. My issue is I have a PDF document that is actually ten documents in one, a series of letters and forms that require about a dozen redundant fields over all 10 documents.

```
TopmostSubform.ControlSheetPG1.RCN::initialize - (JavaScript, client)
RCN.rawValue = app.response("Enter the Report Control Number (RCN)");
if (RCN.rawValue < "" || RCN.rawValue == RCN.rawValue) {

TopmostSubform.ControlSheetPG1.RCN::exit - (JavaScript, client)
RCN.rawValue = RCN.rawValue;
```

As you can see, I have the user enter the information upon initialization, and upon exit I have it update the global data for RCN. My issue is the "if" statement. I need to have the javascript check to see if the field is occupied before it creates the popup box asking for the info. So if the field is occupied with data it skips it and leaves the data alone and goes onto the next field and repeats until all fields have been updated, or checked. I hope all of this makes sense.

Comment: No need for snippet when the code can't really run. Just use regular code-block next time.

Comment: Thanks, just being cautious.